# Fill up a div with equally spaced horizontal lines

Tags: html, css

I need to fill a div with overlying horizontal dotted lines. The lines have a spacing of 5px between them. The height of my div is not fixed, it expands as I add content.

Is there any way to accomplish this using just CSS/HTML? And second, if it's possible, can it be compatible with IE 8 as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way i guess would be if you are using a tiled Background Image.

```
#mydiv
{
background-image:url('lines.png');
background-repeat:repeat-y;
}
```

And check this out http://www.stripegenerator.com/

Comment: This is definitively the solution that let the browser showing the most effect with the least work.

Comment: Thank you! That worked really well with the stripegenerator link.

Answer (score 0):

This will create horizontal dotted lines, with 5px spacing:

```
<hr style="border-top: dotted 1px; margin-bottom: 5px" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine div boxes: one outside as container, then several inside as dotted line creaters. Here's a start:

http://jsfiddle.net/pAW48/

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="fill">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="fill">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="fill">&nbsp;</div>
  ...
```

By setting CSS overflow-y, you can hide the fill divs and add as much as you need.

By playing around with the CSS position attribute and/or margin attribute, you should be able to have the lines as background and add other divs before the lines, if this is what you wish.